# How do I stop Gatsby from wrapping Markdown images in <p> tags and hiding image captions?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-remark-image

I’ve set up my site with the [Gatsby starter blog template](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/).

In my Markdown files, I use normal Markdown notation for inserting images with captions. For some reason—I assume it’s because of the `gatsby-remark-images` plugin et. al.—my images are automatically wrapped in `<p>` tags along with a bunch of other things I don’t understand.

This is the source in Safari:

```
<p>
<span class="gatsby-resp-image-wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-width: 630px; ">
<span class="gatsby-resp-image-background-image" style="padding-bottom: 75.31645569620254%; position: relative; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,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&quot;); background-size: cover; display: block; transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s; opacity: 0;"></span><img class="gatsby-resp-image-image" alt="Tøyen barnehage er en av fem kommunale barnehager i Nittedal. <cite>Nittedal kommune</cite>" title="Tøyen barnehage er en av fem kommunale barnehager i Nittedal. <cite>Nittedal kommune</cite>" src="/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/828fb/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg" srcset="/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/ff44c/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg 158w,
/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/a6688/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg 315w,
/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/828fb/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg 630w,
/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/0ede0/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg 945w,
/static/6c4a2d09ef212e5058dc411fbe918fb9/6a068/toyen-barnehage-2.jpg 960w" sizes="(max-width: 630px) 100vw, 630px" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; vertical-align: middle; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s; color: inherit; box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px 400px inset;" loading="lazy" decoding="async">
</span>
</p>
```

I’ve tried researching this. I understand it’s a bunch of features for loading images more efficiently and hence better and so on.

The fancy features are fine, but I need my image to be wrapped in a `figure` with a `figcaption`—not a `<p>` tag. (A `div` with a `p` for caption would of course also be fine.)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a default configuration and there's no options in the [`gatsby-remark-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images/#options)  that to customize the output, you'll need to add a custom component rendering. Luckily, there's a plugin that makes this configuration far easy: [`gatsby-remark-figure-caption`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-figure-caption/). Just add it inside the `gatsby-transformer-remark`:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    options: {
      plugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-figure-caption`,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]
```

And will output:

```
<figure>
  <img src="path-to-image.jpg">
  <figcaption>image with description</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that I need to add another plugin—`gatsby-remark-unwrap-images`—before the plug-in you suggested. Or am I doing something wrong?

Also: is there a way to remove the formatting the plug-in seems to add? Such as padding and margins etc. I don’t want any of this in my HTML.

Comment: It shouldn't need any extra dependencies but it depends on your module versions. If using both worked keep it like that. Ideally, CSS styles (margins, paddings, etc)  should be managed by the styles rather than the structure (less headaches).

Comment: Yes, I agree. That’s why I wonder how I can disable things like this: `<span class="gatsby-resp-image-wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-width: 630px; ">` from automatically being added. Can I alter the plug-in somehow? Or is all of this managed in “options” in `gatsby-config.js`? Because I can’t find it… Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: None of the plugins accept further customizations rather than the class name. So you'll need to use CSS to remove the default styling

Comment: Will my CSS styling override these? I'm specifically referring to the default "max-width" I see is being applied. I think this is what's causing the problem.

Comment: Unless you add `! important`inline styles has priority among CSS files

Comment: I’m not getting this to work :( My figures are set to a max-width of 42rem, while my paragraphs are set to a max-width of 25. My images are set to width 100%. The images are still not extending over, centered, like [here](https://magnuskolstad.com/truet-politimann-med-balltre-bare-prov-a-komme-inn-bare-prov.html). What am I doing wrong? Also, as to the plug-ins: they’re wrapping the images in two sets of spans. How does that work? You can’t wrap block elements in spans? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/32953) for a complete excerpt. A solution would make my day :)

Comment: This plugin isn't compabible to Gatsby@4