# Images getting wrapped in extra div when using combination of gatsby-plugin-mdx and gatsby-remark-images

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I'm using the following versions:

```
"gatsby": "^4.21.1",
"gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^4.0.0",
"gatsby-remark-images": "^6.21.0",
"remark-unwrap-images": "^3.0.1",
```

And I have the following in place as part of my `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    {
        resolve: "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
        options: {
            gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
                {
                    resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
                    options: {
                        linkImagesToOriginal: false,
                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    },
                },
            ],
            mdxOptions: {
                remarkPlugins: [wrapESMPlugin("remark-unwrap-images")]
            }
        },
    },
```

Then in my code I make use of the `MDXProvider` to override the rendering of some components like so:

```
        <MDXProvider components={{ img: SomeComponent }}>
            {children}
        </MDXProvider>
```

Before upgrading to use the latest versions of `gatsby-plugin-mdx` and `gatsby-remark-images` this used to work nicely and I'd end up with my custom component being rendered correctly.

Since the update I'm finding that an extra `div` is wrapping the image which appears to be coming from `gatsby-remark-images` (although looking at the source code I can't see how or where).

As a result, this changes the behaviour of `MDXProvider` since it now thinks it's a `div` instead of an `img` which is a problem.

Has anyone encountered this or have a suggestion on how to resolve it?

**Note**: This is not the same as the issue with images getting wrapped in `p` Which can be resolved by using `remark-unwrap-images` per my `gatsby-config.js` as shown above. Also, further to this `gatsby-remark-figure-caption` does not appear to work in `gatsby` 4+.

Comment: check this plugin : [gatsby-remark-unwrap-images](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-unwrap-images/) , check this as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957098/how-do-i-stop-gatsby-from-wrapping-markdown-images-in-p-tags-and-hiding-image

Comment: seems like someone else encountered this. but this isn't considered as a bug. check this: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/37049